# How to restrict foreach on a streaming RDD only once upon receiver completion

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have created a Custom Receiver to fetch records pertaining to a specific query  from Elastic Search and have implemented Streaming RDD transformations to process the data generated by the receiver.

The final RDD is a sorted list of name value pairs and I want to read the top 20 results programmatically rather than write to an external file.

I use "foreach" on the RDD and take the top 20 values into a list. I see that forEach is processed every time there is a new microbatch from the receiver.

However, I want the foreach computation to be done only once when the receiver has finished fetching all the records from Elastic Search and before the streaming context is killed so that I can populate the results into a list and process it in my driver program.

Comment: could you add some code that illustrates what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

first you should create one Static empty Rdd and then union with your Streaming Rdds. Once your Streaming context goes stop, Apply foreach to compute your static Rdd.